# bash script does not appear in ps aux output : how to kill?

Tags: bash, kill, pid

I have done some googling on this but not come up with an answer ... frustration is setting in!

I want to kill my bash script. This executes various other processes. I can kill any process for which I have a PID; but ps aux | grep myuserid shows up only the 'other processes', not the script itself.

How can I kill the script? Perhaps this means 'how can I get a PID for the script?' Then I can kill it.

Thanks, and have a great weekend (-:

m

PS THANKS for the many great answers to previous questions here ... it's a daily resource for me. Invaluable.

---

SOLVED!
Well, the test ('development=true) it ran its natural course while I googled, head-scratched and consulted the combined expertise here. Now started again as a nohup job with the 'development' tag set to false. This time I CAN see it on the ps aux | grep me output. Sigh, it's been a long day.

Thanks to all that contributed answers, comme toujours.
Enjoy the weekend.

Comment: Did you try `ps aux | grep script_name`?
And of course you have confirmed the script is actually running at the time you are trying to find it?

Comment: htop is a great tool for this. `/` to search ([even `\\` for incremental filtering in latest version 1.0](http://htop.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=downloads))

Answer (score 1):

If you know your rogue script's file name, you might try `pgrep -f my_script_name`.  If it works it will show you the pid.  Alternately you can use `pkill` to directly try to kill any matching process.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this with:

```
killall scriptname
```